# How to create a CSV file if it doesn't exist?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to get excel to check for the existence of a CSV file, and if it doesn't exist, create it.  I've tried doing this several ways, but I can't seem to get anything working.  Here's my code so far.

```
If Dir("C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\") = "" Then
                MkDir "C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\"
                Dim ws As Worksheet
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name = MyCell.Value Then
                        ws.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv", xlCSV
                        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv"
                        Cells.Select
                        Selection.Delete
                        ActiveWorkbook.Close True

                        LastRowCusip = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "BW").End(xlUp).Row
                        Set Rng = Range("BG5:BW" & LastRowCusip)
                        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv"
                        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 3 'last used row
                        Rng.Copy Range("A" & LR)
                        ActiveWorkbook.Close True

                    End If
                Next
            End If
```

As soon as I get to this line:

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv"

Excel shuts down!!

All I want to do is test for the existence of a CSV file and it it doesn't exist, create it on a user's desktop, based on each user's sUserName, which comes from here.

```
sUserName = Environ$("username")
```

Can someone please help me get this working?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the sheet out of the workbook first.

Change these lines:

```
ws.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv", xlCSV
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv"
```

To the following lines

```
   ws.Copy 
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\" & sUserName & "\Desktop\DataDump\DataDump.csv", xlCSV
```

When saving a `worksheet` as CSV it saves the entire active workbook to the file and leaves it open. So, in your code, you are trying to open a file that is already open.

The code above will pull the worksheet into a new workbook and save it as a CSV (with only 1 sheet, which is required for a CSV).

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense.  I knew it was something like that.  Thanks for the help Scott!!

Comment: If Scott's anwser helped you please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers helps those that follow you, rewards Scott for his effort and increases the likelihood of your future questions receiving answers.  Currently you have 8 open questions.